# Xamarin Wrong Count of NavigationStack in OnAppearing after Navigatig Back

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the following method to set the pagenumber of my current page:

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    // Page number
    _pageNumber = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count - 2;
}
```

Everything works fine, if I am navigating forward and pushing a new page onto the stack like this:

```
private async void btnContinue_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Proceed to next view
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());
}
```

However, when I am navigating back from one page, the OnAppearing() method seems to be called before the previous page is popped. Thus, the `_pageNumber` variable will effectively be the one of the previous page. How do I work around that? I thought of placing it inside the constructor but the NavigationStack.Count always returns 0 in there.
My pages are **dynamically** programmed, therefore, I cannot hardcode the page number into the page because the same page is called but the values are changing based on the number of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be an expected  effect .

When the **PopAsync** method is invoked, the following events occur:

1. The page calling **PopAsync** has its **OnDisappearing** override invoked.
2. The page being returned to has its **OnAppearing** override invoked.
3. The **PopAsync** task returns.

So if you want to get current count of NavigationStack , you could improve the answer like following :

In the demo , I used MessageingCenter to pass the current of NavigationStack to last page . And the label will display the current NavigationStack  .

```
bool isFirstLoad = true;

protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();

    if(isFirstLoad)
    {
      label.Text = Navigation.NavigationStack.Count.ToString();
      isFirstLoad = false;
    }

    MessagingCenter.Subscribe<Object,int>(this, "pop", (arg, num) => {

      label.Text = (num-1).ToString();

     });

}
```

And when you call Pop

```
 private async void Button_Clicked_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   MessagingCenter.Send<Object,int>(this, "pop", Navigation.NavigationStack.Count);
   await Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Yep, that should do it! Thanks!!

Comment: Don't forget to upvote my question if you liked it;)